# iTextSharp table on every page

Tags: itext, pdfptable

I need to make a PDF document with a table containing multiple rows and columns that shows client information.
I also need to show the products of this client. I create a loop which creates a new table with multiple rows and columns and the product information.

This works fine. I start with the client table and next I have multiple product tables. I've set `KeepTogether to True` and `SpacingAfter = 20f`. So after each product table I have some white space.

When the client has many products the product tables continue on the next page. Exactly what I want.

But on the new page I want to start with the client table again. What is the best workflow to do this?

Comment: Can you use the PdfPageEventHandler class? [PdfPTable as a header in iTextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321526/pdfptable-as-a-header-in-itextsharp)

Comment: Events are a great way to do this but you could also possibly just use the table's native `HeaderRows` property which will automatically repeat the number of rows specified on every page.

Comment: It depends. Maybe using a Form XObject for the client information is more efficient (less redundant content in the document). I'm wondering if this question qualifies as a StackOverflow question. It's really too broad. There are at least three different ways to achieve this (page events, header rows, use stationery) and the question isn't specific enough to make the call on which approach is best. We're almost neighbors and you're going to use iText in a commercial product (MapWindow). Waarom neem je niet gewoon eens contact op met onze Belgische business developer?

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions. I'll look into the PdfPageEventHandler class and also try nested tables with a header. @Bruno: It seems you know me, but I don't remember you. The project I'm using iTextSharp has nothing to do with MapWindow GIS *AND* MapWindow GIS is not a commercial product. It's Open Source and has been for the last 15 years.

Comment: If the table is identical on every page, make sure you create a Form XObject (`PdfTemplate`) so that you can reuse the table content instead of constructing the content over and over again for every page.