# Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'System.Web.UI.Page' via nested type 'PrintToPdf._events'

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have been trying to add an image to all pages using `iTextSharp`.

According to this [web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321526/pdfptable-as-a-header-in-itextsharp/2326193#2326193) I need to look into the `PdfPageEventHelper` of `iTextSharp`.

It provides a method called `OnEndPage` that allows such things.

Basically, treat the image as being in the header or footer of the document, and use absolute positioning to put it where you want, instead of just in the flow of the page content.

The below code response with error :

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'System.Web.UI.Page'
>   via nested type 'PrintToPdf._events'

On :

```
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(imagepath)));
```

Is there any way to insert the image in the same way in all pages?

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance.

```
class _events : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

        table.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - document.LeftMargin - document.RightMargin;
        PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(2);

        string imagepath = @"Img\Logo.jpg";

        PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(imagepath)));
        cell2.Colspan = 2;
        table2.AddCell(cell2);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(table2);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.LeftMargin, document.PageSize.Height - 36, writer.DirectContent);
    }
}



private void PdfFiles()
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    pnPrint.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

    string imagepath = @"Img\Logo.jpg";

    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 10f, 20f);

    try
    {
        _events e = new _events();
        PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        pw.PageEvent = e;

        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDoc.Open();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Image image = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath(imagepath));
            image.Alignment = Image.ALIGN_LEFT;
            pdfDoc.Add(image);
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

**Edit #1**

```
protected class MyEvent : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    Image image;
    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        image = Image.GetInstance(@"C:\\intepub\\wwwroot\\img\\Logo.jpg");
        image.SetAbsolutePosition(12, 300);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        writer.DirectContent.AddImage(image);
    }
}


        // step 1
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20f, 20f, 10f, 20f);

        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);            
        MyEvent e = new MyEvent();
        writer.PageEvent = e;

        // step 3
        pdfDoc.Open();

        // step 4
        pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

        // step 5
        pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Please do not use `HTMLWorker`, it is obsolete. You can use `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Okay, thank you! But I have the same error

Comment: There are too many errors in your code. For instance: you create an `Image` object for a logo in the `OnEndPage` method. This means that the same image bytes will be added to the PDF as many times as there are pages, resulting in a bloated PDF. It is no use wasting time trying to fix your code. The best way is to throw away your code, read some decent documentation, and start anew from scratch.

Comment: As for the error you mention: `System.Web.UI.Page` is a C# class, not an iTextSharp class. I don't see it anywhere in the code you share. This tells me that any assumption that your problem is iText-related is wrong.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thank you for help; I have resetted my code please see **Edit #1** in my first question. Now the error is `The document has no pages. `