# ITextSharp Add Logo along with text in Header

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to add logo and some text detail in header using foll

```
iTextSharp.text.Image i = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(logoPath);
HeaderFooter headerFooter = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(new Chunk(i, 20, 0)), new Phrase(user.Organization.Title + "\n"  + materialIndex + "\n" + priceList.Title));
headerFooter.Alignment = 0;
document.SetMargins(20, 20, 100, 0);
document.Header = headerFooter;
```

Issue with this approach is, logo overlapped with text detail as per shown in attached image
[image]

I want to display logo and text side by side. is it possible? I am using 4.1.6 version of ITextSharp.

Comment: Have you considered using page events instead of the old `HeaderFooter`?

Comment: Yes I tried that but it overlapped to content too

Comment: Did you do it using a table object from your page event handler?

Comment: no I using simple event function

Comment: Then you should look at stack overflow answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326193/1729265).